# Belongs_to only recognized by console, not server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, models, belongs-to

I've got a really weird problem with my project. I've got 2 models, the one is Link and the other Category. I've got a index view where all the links should be listed, together with the corresponding category names. When running the server and trying to use

```
<%= link.category.name %>
```

I get an error page with the following:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

But when I open the console and write:

```
link = Link.find(1) #there is currently only one link
link.category.name
```

It returns the correct category name.

Here are my Models and schema.rb:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :category_id, :description, :title, :url, :visible

  belongs_to :category

  scope :visible, lambda { where(visible: true) }
end
```

.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :links

end
```

.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130420070717) do

  create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  add_index "categories", ["id"], :name => "index_categories_on_id"

  create_table "links", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.string   "url"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.boolean  "visible"
    t.datetime "created_at",  :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  :null => false
  end

  add_index "links", ["category_id"], :name => "index_links_on_category_id"
  add_index "links", ["id"], :name => "index_links_on_id"
end
```

How can this happen? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: can you see if all of your links are tied to a category? e.g. have a category_id that's not nil for some reason?
Try to do this and tell me what it returns:  `Link.all.collect(&:category_id).include?(nil)`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! When I execute it in the console it returns false. There is currently only 1 link in the db, it has a correct category_id.

Comment: huh, i don't know then.. can you show your view code maybe?

Comment: It would help to see the relevant controller and view code for the index action.

Comment: I found the problem, the category_id WAS wrong. I'm sorry for the wrong info I gave. I added a solution to the problem, maybe I can help others facing the same problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can help others facing the same issue.

The category_id was assigned to the link by a form which queries the existing categories from the db.

```
<%= f.select(:category_id, @categories.collect { |c| c.name }) %>
```

The category I wanted to assign has the id = 1. After selecting the category from the dropdown menu, the link.category_id was 0, it should have been 1.

UPDATE:

I fixed the wrong index by:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, :prompt => "Select a category" %>
```